# Python importing class attributes into method local namespace

Tags: python, class, namespaces

I have been wondering for a while if there is easier way to assign class attributes to method local namespace. For example, in `dosomething` method, I explicitly make references to `self.a` and `self.b`:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 20

    def dosomething(self):
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        return(a + b)
```

But sometimes I have a lot of variables (more than 10) and it gets messy to type and look at - I would have bunch of `var = self.var` statements at the beginning of a method.

Is there any way to do this more compact way? (I know updating `local()` is not a good idea)

Edit: Ideally, what I want is:

```
def dosomething(self):
    populate_local_namespace('a', 'b')
    return(a + b)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? What's wrong with having a one-line `dosomething` method that looks like "`return (self.a + self.b)`"? What benefit do you expect to get from this?

Comment: I have my reasons - especially, I'm doing complex calculations and many `self.`'s make expressions very long and ugly.

Comment: @munn why would you want to pollute the code with all those _self_'s ..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Q. Is there any way to do this more compact way?

**1.** If the variables are read-only, it would be reasonably Pythonic to factor-out a multi-variable accessor method:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 20
        self.c = 30

    def _read_vars(self):
        return self.a, self.b, self.c

    def dosomething(self):
        a, b, c = self._read_vars()
        return a + b * c

    def dosomethingelse(self):
        a, b, c = self._read_vars()
        return a - b * c
```

If the variables aren't read-only, it is best to stick with `self.inst_var = value`.  That is the normal way to write Python code and is usually what most people expect.

---

**2.** Once in a while you will see people abbreviate `self` with a shorter variable name.  It is used when the readability benefits of decluttering outweigh the readability cost of using a non-standard variable name:

```
def updatesomethings(s):
    s.a, s.b, s.c = s.a + s.c, s.b - s.a, s.c * s.b
```

---

**3.** Another way to handle a very large number instance variable is to store them in a mutable container for ease of packing and unpacking:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i):
        self._vars = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]

    def fancy_stuff(self):
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = self._vars
        a += d * h - g
        b -= e * f - c
        g = a + b - i
        self._vars[:] = a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
```

---

**4.** There is also a dictionary manipulation approach that would work, but it has a code smell that most Pythonistas would avoid:

```
def updatesomethings(self):
    a = 100
    b = 200
    c = 300
    vars(self).update(locals())
    del self.self
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually this is exactly what I have been doing. But this is not flexible enough, since when I want to change the variables I have to change both places. It would be great if there is a way where I can just pass the name of an attribute to a function as a string and the attribute becomes a local variable.

Comment: @joon I've added some other options for you as well.

Comment: Yes 4 does look scary :) I would just use calling function way (`_read_vars()`) for now. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: Isn't it time for a variation of the splash-operator to automatically add arguments from `__init__` to an object?! Analog to the *args and **kwargs we could do a `+arg1`, `+args=None`, which would automatically add the argument as an attribute to an object, sparing the writer and reader to go over superfluos repetition of assigning `__init__`-arguments to object-attributes.

Comment: concerning 3: can you explain what `self._vars[:] = a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i` does and why you didn't use `self._vars = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]`?

Answer (score -2):

You can easily solve this problem with a tradeoff, by storing the variables in a dictionary.

```
data = {}
copy_to_local_variables = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for var_name in copy_to_local_variables:
    data[var_name] = getattr(self, var_name)
```

(Though I am unable to understand why you need to copy class attributes to method local namespace)

Comment: Won't this just make a dict named `data` with those variables instead of making local variables referencing to class attributes? I don't think this is what I want.

Answer (score -2):

I found another way:

```
def dosomething(self):
    for key in ['a', 'b']:
       exec('{} = self.{}'.format(key, key))

    return(a + b)
```

I don't know if this is dangerous or not. Would be great if someone can comment on this.

Comment: It would be dangerous if key would ever be a string that came from an untrusted source.

Comment: It is also likely to be very slow, since every time the exec() call is made Python has to lex, parse, compile, and execute the brand-new statement as though seeing it for the first time.